# Integrating two exponentials produces a cosine integral? Can somebody explain?

Tags: integration, exponential-function, signal-processing

I discovered the following conversation that I do not understand. It reads:

$$\int_{-U_1}^0 {(\frac {u_1} {U_1}+1)e^{-j\omega_1u_1}}~du_1+\int_0^{U_1} {(-\frac {u_1} {U_1}+1)e^{-j\omega_1u_1}}~du_1 =
2 \int_0^{U_1} {(-\frac {u_1} {U_1}+1)cos(\omega_1u_1)}~du_1$$

How did they get from the two exponential integrals to the one with the cosine? Can somebody explain?

Comment: They are complex conjugate exponentials if you rearrange the integrals properly.

Comment: You could also directly use Euler's formula to split both exponentials into cosine and sine, and then see how the $j$maginary part cancels out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply change the variable $v=-u_1$. Then you you can write the sum of your integrals as
$$
\int_0^{U_1}\left( -\frac{v}{U_1}+1 \right) \left( e^{-j\omega_1 v}+e^{j\omega_1 v} \right) 
$$
and if you remember that
$$
e^{jx}=\cos x +j\sin x
$$
you get your integral...

**EDIT** how to change the limits of integration.
Take your first integral 
$$
\int_{-U_1}^0 {(\frac {u_1} {U_1}+1)e^{-j\omega_1u_1}}~du_1 
$$
then put $v=-u_1$ and you get (remember you have $dv=-du_1$)
$$
-\int_{U_1}^0 {(\frac {-v} {U_1}+1)e^{-j\omega_1 (-v)}}~dv 
$$
then you can exchange the limit of the integral and change sign like this
$$
\int_a^bf(x)dx = -\int_b^a f(x)dx
$$
and therefore you get
$$
\int_{0}^{U_1} {(-\frac {v} {U_1}+1)e^{j\omega_1 v}}~dv 
$$
Is that clearer?
Let me know if is ok.

Comment: So now we have to add
$$
\int_{0}^{U_1} {(-\frac {v} {U_1}+1)e^{j\omega_1 v}}~dv 
$$
to
$$
\int_0^{U_1} {(-\frac {u_1} {U_1}+1)e^{-j\omega_1u_1}}~du_1
$$
But the dependent variables are different $u_1$ and $v$. So how can  we add them?

Comment: Hi @MartinMarinov the variable used in the integration is what I used to call "mute". Id means that it does not matter how it is called. You can make the variable change in the second integral $u_1=v$ if it makes easier to understand. The second integral would not change.

Answer (score 2):

The first integral on the left side of the equation can be rewritten as

$$\int_{-U_1}^0 {(\frac {u_1} {U_1}+1)e^{-j\omega_1u_1}}~du_1=
\int_{0}^{U_1} {(-\frac {u_1} {U_1}+1)e^{j\omega_1u_1}}~du_1$$

and from

$$\cos x=\frac{1}{2}(e^{jx}+e^{-jx})$$

you obtain the result.

**EDIT:**

With $x=-u_1$ (and $dx=-du$) you get for the first integral on the left side of the equation

$$-\int_{U_1}^0 {(-\frac {x} {U_1}+1)e^{j\omega_1x}}~dx$$

The sign is changed by interchanging the lower and upper integration limits:

$$\int_{0}^{U_1} {(-\frac {x} {U_1}+1)e^{j\omega_1x}}~dx$$

Comment: Thanks! I suspected this is the answer but I don't understand why rewriting this is valid.
Can you, please, show me the steps (or name the rule) that allows you to change the limits of integration like this?

Comment: Will edit my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Hey, @Umberto, thanks. Yes, I will need some clarification. My integration skills have become quite rusty, haven't done this for almost a full year now :)

Comment: @MartinMarinov I added the substitution to my answer. Please have a look.